# Revoke access for an access_token received via MS Active Directory authentication

Tags: active-directory, passport.js, azure-ad-msal, passport-azure-ad

I am currently using `passport-azure-ad` and `@azure/msal-node`    nodejs library to authenticate users for my APIs. When the user successfully authenticates via his/her microsoft account we receive an access_token, the user can call our APIs with that access_token.
Now if we disable the user's account from the Azure admin panel, the user's already existing access_token should be invalidated and he/she should not be able to call our APIs with that access_token.

How can we do this please?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can't.

I believe that the spec. doesn't allow access tokens to be revoked.

You can, however, [revoke refresh tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/users-revoke-access).

When the access token expires, the refresh token won't be honoured and the user will be logged out.

Going forward, [continuous access evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/concept-continuous-access-evaluation) will be of use but it hasn't been implemented in many apps. to date.

Comment: thank you @rbrayb , can I reduce the access_token expiry to 5 mins ? so that after the refresh token is revoked, the maximum period the user will be able to use the access token is 5 mins.

Comment: Yup - that will work.